# $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \int_{1}^x \frac{dt}{t} + O(1)$ help deriving it

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, approximation, harmonic-numbers

On page 5 of: [Probabilistic Number Theory by Dr.J¨orn Steuding](https://web.archive.org/web/20111222233654/http://hdebruijn.soo.dto.tudelft.nl/jaar2004/prob.pdf), there's

> $\sum_{n=2}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n} \lt \int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t} \lt \sum_{n=1}^{[x] - 1}$
>   Therefore integration yields:
>      $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \int_{1}^x \frac{dt}{t} + O(1)$

I'm not sure how they arrived at that conclusion.

Comment: Draw a diagram of the curve $y=\frac 1x$ and the rectangles above and below it with vertical sides at integer points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I there there is quite a bit missing to make that a rigorous argument. It isn't hard to reconstruct one though.

From the inequality

$$\sum_{n=2}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n} \lt \int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t} \lt \sum_{n=1}^{[x] - 1} \frac{1}{n}$$

we would like to extract an upper and lower bound for $$\sum_{n=1}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n}$$ so take the inequality at $[x]+1$ to deduce $$\int_{1}^{[x]+1} \frac{dt}{t} \lt \sum_{n=1}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n}$$ in fact we might weaken this to $$\int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t} \lt \sum_{n=1}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n}$$ and add one to both sides of the original inequality to deduce $$1 + \sum_{n=2}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n} \lt 1 + \int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t}.$$

Hence $$\int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t} \lt \sum_{n=1}^{[x]} \frac{1}{n} \lt 1 + \int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t}$$

from this it is clear that the sum is equal to $\int_{1}^{[x]} \frac{dt}{t}$ some constant ($O(1)$).

Comment: Brilliant!  I understand it completely now.